# How can I trace only non built-in function or class method

Tags: php, xdebug

How can I trace only non built-in function or class method into a file?

I have used xdebug, but it seems to trace all the functions either built-in or not built-in functions.
Does Xdebug have the functionality of dealing with traces that way, or could somebody introduce some tools to fulfill my need?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list of built-in functions (with get_defined_functions) and strip them out. The xdebug trace format is a text format.

Comment: Thanks Evert, but I really want a tool can do that for me

Comment: Well, knowing the PHP space pretty well; I'm pretty certain you are now officially venturing in territory people haven't written tools for yet. Time to get coding, or figure out a different way to solve your problem.